# Pointer variables generated in functions cannot be passed in parameters of function pointers

Tags: c, parameter-passing, function-pointers

Topic:
Given a positive integer with no more than 5 digits, require:

1. Find out how many digits it is;
2. Output each digit separately;
3. Output each digit in reverse order. For example, if the original digit is 321, 123 should be output.

When I called the following program using a function pointer, I found that the parameters "number" and "digit" could not be passed to each function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inputNumber(int *number){
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", number);
    while(*number <= 0 || *number > 9999){
        if(*number <= 0){
            printf("The number is not positive integer! Retry!\nEnter number: ");
        }
        if(*number > 9999){
            printf("The number is more than 5 digits! Retry!\nEnter number: ");
        }
        scanf_s("%d", number);
    }
}

void outputDigit(int *number, int *digit){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; *number != 0; i++){
        *number /= 10;
    }
    *digit = i;
    //printf("%d\n", *number);    Test Output
    printf("The number is %d digits!\n", i);
}

void outputNumber(int *number, int *digit){
    int base = 10;
    int temp = *number;
    for(int i = 1; i < *digit - 1; i++){
        base *= 10;
    }
    //printf("%d %d\n", *number, temp);    Test Output
    for(int i = 0; i < *digit; i++){
        printf("%d ", temp / base);
        temp -= temp / base * base;
        base /= 10;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void outputReverseNumber(int *number, int *digit){
    int temp = *number;
    for(int i = 0; i < *digit; i++){
        printf("%d ", temp % 10);
        temp = (temp - temp % 10) / 10;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void function(int *number, int *digit, void (*fun[])(int*, int*)){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        fun[i](number, digit);
    }
}

int main(){
    int *number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *digit = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    void (*fun[3])(int*, int*) = {outputDigit, outputNumber, outputReverseNumber};
    inputNumber(number);
    function(number, digit, fun);
    free(number);
    free(digit);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want parameters in function pointers to be passed by pointer variables generated by other functions.

Comment: A couple of things: First [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc); Secondly don't allocate single integer values dynamically. Use the pointer-to operator `&` to get a pointer to the variable instead. Like `int number = 0; inputNumber(&number);`

Comment: And what is the actual problem you have? When you say that you can't pass `number` and `digt` to the functions, what is really happening? Do you get build errors or warnings? Then copy-paste the full and complete build-log into your question (together with the command and options used to build). If you get unexpected results, then what is the input you give your program? What is the expected *and* actual output? And if you get crashes, what does your debugger say it happens?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: As an educated guess: You don't get the results you expect. Which is because `outputDigit` *modifies* the values. Always work on copies, don't use the pointed-to values directly in your calculations. And unless this exercise is about pointers, why are you using pointers to begin with? What is your actual assignment? What is its actual requirements and limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with parameter passing. The problem is that you keep dividing numbers inside `outputDigit` and thereby ensuring that the original number is zero upon leaving the function. That can be fixed by using a temporary variable instead:

```c
void outputDigit(int *number, int *digit){
    int i;
    int tmp = *number;
    for(i = 0; tmp != 0; i++){
        tmp /= 10;
    }
    *digit = i;
    printf("The number is %d digits!\n", i);
}
```

Another bug is that `*number > 9999` checks that a number isn't larger than *four* digits, not five. Should be `99999`.

General code review:

- Avoid `scanf_s` since it is poorly standardized. Original `scanf` actually supports reading a fixed amount of characters if you check the result. However, in this specific case it would have been *much* more convenient to read the input as a string with `fgets`, since base-10 decimal digits is a cumbersome format forcing you to use division over and over.
- It makes no sense at all to use function pointers here. The various functions in your array do unrelated tasks, so generic programming with an abstraction layer only makes the program hard to read for nothing gained. I take it you are just using them for learning purposes.
- The big bug here could have been avoided if you use *const correctness*, meaning that pointer parameters that aren't supposed to be modified should be marked read-only. That is:

  ```
  void outputDigit(const int *number, int *digit);
  void outputNumber(const int *number, const int *digit);
  void outputReverseNumber(const int *number, const int *digit)
  ```

  Although now the functions have different types so the function pointer array can no longer be used either.
- In general don't mix up algorithms (calculating number of digits) with user I/O (printing or taking input). Programmers don't expect a function named `outputDigit` to calculate a digit, they expect it to print one.
- Using dynamic allocation for a single `int` is senseless. Similarly, casting the result of `malloc` is pointless.
- Always use typedef when dealing with function pointers, for readability. In this case you could have done:

  ```
  typedef void func_t (int*, int*);
  ...
  func_t* fun[3] = {outputDigit, outputNumber, outputReverseNumber};
  ...
  void function(int *number, int *digit, func_t* fun[3])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As you overwrite `number` in every functon with zero, then next call is using that modified value. You have been caught by traps of the side effects.

You need to restore it before every call:

```
void function(int *number, int *digit, void (*fun[])(int*, int*))
{
    int savedNumber = *number;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fun[i](number, digit);
        *number = savedNumber;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6GWKqbfMq